# Why doesn't getopts in bash yield : (per docs) when an option is missing its associated argument?

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I'm relatively new to this field, and I'm running my shell script named "statsrandomrun.sh" with following code snippets:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts "m:s:xh" opt; do
  case $opt in
    m)
      MU=$OPTARG; mflag=true; ;;
    s)
      SIGMA=$OPTARG; sflag=true; ;;
    h)
      usage; exit;;
    x)
      xflag=true ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "HaHa! Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

but it seems though whenever I pass this command

```
/.statsrandomrun.sh -m
```

I never see

```
echo "HaHa! Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
```

working, which I implemented in the above snippet. My bash just shows me some other message:

```
option requires an argument -- m
```

which I did not obviously put in my code. Also there follows another line

```
Invalid option: -
```

I expect this to take place, because the output from `help getopts` contains the following:

> If a required argument is not found, getopts places a ':' into NAME and sets OPTARG to the option character found.

What is happening? Any ideas?
I'd appreciate any help in advance :)

Comment: Here's a couple of resources.. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035?highlight=%28getopts%29. Both of these sites have a lot of good information about shell scripting.

Comment: When I run your script: `script.sh -m` I get `script.sh: option requires an argument -- m` and then one line below `Invalid option: -`

Comment: What's the "shebang" line in your script?

Comment: @gleen I just found out that when I use `#!/bin/sh` I get the msg `No arg for -m option` whereas when I use `#!/bin/bash` I receive `option requires an argument --m` message. So I edited the post.

But with `#!/bin/bash` I still don't get the echo msg I want.

Comment: If you want more control than getopts provides (including control over error messages), do the parsing yourself. See [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035)

Comment: @I0_ol After I changed my shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, I see these messages too  but that isn't the thing I wanted bash to show me. I wanted my echo `"haha ! option -m requires an argument"`, not `option requires an argument -- m`. The latter one is built-in msg, I guess.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually it's based on this source [http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial). It says `:` would activate in such case as mine.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I notice you erased your comment just now. I'll try to look up to your source [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035). Maybe I need some customization to get things work, like you said. Thanks.

Comment: btw, the docs say that `$OPTARG`, not `$name` (which is in your case `$opt`), will be set to `:` in the relevant case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nop, the docs say `$name` is set to `:` and `$OPTARG` is set to the option character, but only in **silence mode** . In **non silence mode**, `?` is instead placed in `$name` and  `$OPTARG` is unset, and a diagnostic messsage is printed. That explains everything! I was forcing **silence mode** option to work in **non silence mode**. Also this explains why I see this seemingly unnecessary line `Invalid option -`. Case solved... Thxs everyone.

Comment: Feel free to write up the above as an answer -- that way you can accept it to mark your problem solved, and if it's helpful to other folks they can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, which is `help getopts`,

> getopts: getopts optstring name [arg]
>
> OPTSTRING contains the option letters to be recognized; if a letter
>      is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument,
>      which should be separated from it by white space.
>
> getopts reports errors in one of two ways.  If the first character
>      of OPTSTRING is a colon, getopts uses silent error reporting.  In
>      this mode, no error messages are printed. ................  If a
>      required argument is not found, getopts places a ':' into NAME and
>      sets OPTARG to the option character found.  If getopts is not in
>      silent mode, ........... If a required argument is not found, a '?'
>      is placed in NAME, OPTARG is unset, and a diagnostic message is
>      printed.

As I implemented my getopts function in **non-silence mode**, this missing argument after `/.statsrandomrun.sh -m` triggered `?` to be stored in `$Name` (in my case `$opt`) with no content in `$OPTARG`.

So these lines of code were executed:

```
  \?)
  echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
  exit 1
  ;;
```

which produced `Invalid option: -` together with *built-in diagnostic* msg.

Instead to get the result I wanted I should have used silence mode as in

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":m:s:xh" opt; do
#codes
done
```

by adding a preceding colon in OPTSTRING.